# Order of cyclic groups of residue classes Mod p (Reference)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cyclic-groups

> Given a prime $p$ and a non-trivial residue class $r$ (not equal to $0,1,p-1$), what is the order $d$ of the cyclic group $C$ with generator $r$ such that:
>   $$
> C= \{ x\mid x=r^k(\hbox{mod } p) \} ?
> $$

Comment: Whoever downvoted could at least comment on why, so I will restrain myself from such "bad questions" in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a hard question.

It is not even known when the order of $2$ is $p-1$. See [Artin's conjecture on primitive roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin's_conjecture_on_primitive_roots).

Comment: Ouch... thank you. Really hoped there was an answer to this. Do I get it right? When $r=p-1$ it is not known if the order is 2? Or you meant that it is not known if the only groups with order 2 are those with $r=p-1$ I'm upvoting but do you have any "consistent" reference on the problem's hardness?

Comment: @Lorenzo, I meant the order of $2$. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: oh when $r=2$, ok. Any reference anyways? Most of the research I found is focused on different sides of the topic just like giving for granted that the order is "given" (or a hard problem as I now discover). It seems not very natural to me after we look at Euler's totient as $r=p-1$'s order which comes out of fairly basic considerations.